# How can I run terminal commands at startup on a Mac OSX server?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, unix, command-line-interface, daemon

For example, when the server boots I need to start Tomcat, and I need to start an Android emulator, and then issue some commands to it. These are on the path already. I'm familiar with Linux and understand the basics of Daemons, and I suspect it will be something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LaunchDaemons are the preferred way to do this in OS X. Each daemon is controlled by a .plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons (for add-on daemons; the builtin daemons are in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons) which specifies when to start the daemon (e.g. on load, when a connection is received on a TCP port, at certain times, etc), what command and arguments to use to start the daemon, etc.  See the Apple developer docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html), and look in /System/Library/LaunchDaemons for examples.

One big warning if you're used to using other startup systems: by default, launchd expects programs it starts to *not* daemonize themselves. [This page](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatOnMacOS) suggests starting Tomcat with a launchd plist named /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.tomcat.plist containing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.apache.tomcat</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/Tomcat/Home/bin/catalina.sh</string>
        <string>run</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

(Note that catalina.sh is told to "run", *not* "start".)

If you need to launch something that cannot be prevented from daemonizing, you'll need to add something like this to the .plist:

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
<false/>
<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key>
<true/>
```